# Log4cpp Naming Collision for 'DEBUG' detected.

Tags: c++, compilation, pre-compilation, log4cpp

## Issue

When compiling my project, I get an error with the *log4cpp* files. The error is the following : 
`/usr/include/log4cpp/Priority.hh:49:2: erreur: #error Naming collision for 'DEBUG' detected. Please read the FAQ for a workaround.`

## The file

The file referenced by this error is a header installed with Log4cpp. Here it is. The errors are on lines 49, 78 and 109

```c
/*
 * Priority.hh
 *
 * Copyright 2000, LifeLine Networks BV (www.lifeline.nl). All rights reserved.
 * Copyright 2000, Bastiaan Bakker. All rights reserved.
 *
 * See the COPYING file for the terms of usage and distribution.
 */

#ifndef _LOG4CPP_PRIORITY_HH
#define _LOG4CPP_PRIORITY_HH

#include <log4cpp/Portability.hh>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>

/*
 * Optionally work around rudeness in windows.h on Win32.
 */
#ifdef ERROR
#ifdef LOG4CPP_FIX_ERROR_COLLISION

namespace log4cpp {
    static const int _tmpERRORValue = ERROR;
}

#undef ERROR
    static const int ERROR = log4cpp::_tmpERRORValue;
#define ERROR ERROR

#else  // LOG4CPP_FIX_ERROR_COLLISION
#error Naming collision for 'ERROR' detected. Please read the FAQ for a \
       workaround. 
#endif // LOG4CPP_FIX_ERROR_COLLISION 

#endif // ERROR

/*
 * Other Win32 rudeness in EDK.h
 */
#ifdef DEBUG

#ifdef LOG4CPP_FIX_ERROR_COLLISION

#undef DEBUG
#define DEBUG DEBUG

#else  // LOG4CPP_FIX_ERROR_COLLISION
#error Naming collision for 'DEBUG' detected. Please read the FAQ for a \
       workaround. 
#endif // LOG4CPP_FIX_ERROR_COLLISION 

#endif // DEBUG

namespace log4cpp {

    /**
     * The Priority class provides importance levels with which one
     * can categorize log messages.
     **/
    class LOG4CPP_EXPORT Priority {
        public:

        static const int MESSAGE_SIZE; // = 8;

        /**
         * Predefined Levels of Priorities. These correspond to the
         * priority levels used by syslog(3).
         **/
        typedef enum {EMERG  = 0, 
              FATAL  = 0,
                      ALERT  = 100,
                      CRIT   = 200,
                      ERROR  = 300, 
                      WARN   = 400,
                      NOTICE = 500,
                      INFO   = 600,
                      DEBUG  = 700,
                      NOTSET = 800
        } PriorityLevel;

        /**
         * The type of Priority Values
         **/
        typedef int Value;

        /**
         * Returns the name of the given priority value.
         * Currently, if the value is not one of the PriorityLevel values,
         * the method returns the name of the largest priority smaller 
         * the given value.
         * @param priority the numeric value of the priority.
         * @returns a string representing the name of the priority.
         **/
        static const std::string& getPriorityName(int priority) throw();

    /**
     * Returns the value of the given priority name. 
     * This can be either one of EMERG ... NOTSET or a 
     * decimal string representation of the value, e.g. '700' for DEBUG.
     * @param priorityName the string containing the the of the priority
     * @return the value corresponding with the priority name
     * @throw std::invalid_argument if the priorityName does not 
     * correspond with a known Priority name or a number
     **/
        static Value getPriorityValue(const std::string& priorityName)
    throw(std::invalid_argument);
    };
}

#endif // _LOG4CPP_PRIORITY_HH
```

## Research

The only FAQ referencing this issue was I found was on [log4cpp's Sourceforge](http://log4cpp.sourceforge.net/#faq). Here is what it says :

> This is caused by the rudeness of some platforms, which mutilate the
>   namespace with some blunt #defines. To be more precise, the Win32 API
>   includes #defines of 'ERROR' and 'DEBUG'. Since the preprocessor is
>   unaware of C++ naming scopes this results in reserving the words ERROR
>   and DEBUG litterally everywhere. In particular this conflicts with
>   log4cpp::Prioritiy::ERROR and log4cpp::Priority::DEBUG. These latter
>   two names come from log4j, so they are not something we made up
>   ourselves. They Win32 authors should not have rudelessly claimed these
>   generic names through the preprocessor. There are much better
>   alternatives:
>
> ```
> If they use it as an integer constant, declare it using a language construct. Either 'enum {ERROR=1};' or 'static const int ERROR=1;'
> ```
>
> would do fine.
>       Use a less generic name like WIN32API_ERROR to make naming conflicts less likely
>       In case they use it as a flag for conditional compilation, use '#define DEBUG DEBUG' and '#if defined(DEBUG)'. In that case the
>   preprocessor would simply replace all occurrences of 'DEBUG' in the
>   source code with 'DEBUG', in effect leaving everything intact.
>
> Of course the proper solution would be if the offending party would
>   use one of the above methods, but we could have to wait some time for
>   this to actually happen. As an alternative log4cpp can workaround
>   these #defines. The workaround code is enabled by doing #define
>   LOG4CPP_FIX_ERROR_COLLISION 1 before #including any log4cpp header
>   files and after #including all platform headers. For Win32 platforms
>   this #define has already been included in log4cpp/config-win32.h.
>
> Once log4cpp has been updated to the log4j 1.2 API we can get rid of
>   this problem by adopting the new names for log levels.

## Context

The thing is, I am not supposed to change the source code. I can only modify compilation configuration files (this project uses Apache Ant builder, `build.xml` files and bash scripts).

I'm quite new to this project and I can't ask the previous developper for help.

## Question

Has anybody encountered this error before ? Is there any possible workaround other than changing the source codes and it's defines ? Are my environment variables the cause ?

I will continue my search, but any insight would be usefull. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Like it says in the docs, you need to define `LOG4CPP_FIX_ERROR_COLLISION`. If you are not allowed to modify any source, you should be able to do it in your build.xml:

```
<define name="LOG4CPP_FIX_ERROR_COLLISION" value="1" />
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick answer. It seems that it is defined in other parts of the project, in Qt project files (.pro/.pri) and in Makefiles. I will test adding the defines in those. Will keep you posted.